# changing while loops to for loops

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to change this while loop into a for loop and I'm not getting particularly far. I am new ish to programming, so apologies if this is a trivial task.

```
while (read < fileBytes.length
       && (numRead = diStream.read(fileBytes, read, fileBytes.length - read)) >= 0)
{
    read = read + numRead;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to change it to a for?

Comment: It's some what lengthy and wondering if having it in a for loop will enhance readability. Also just generally interested.

Comment: `read = read + numRead` could be changed to `read += numRead`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a C# Programmer, but I will write code which is very similar to what you need.

```
for (int read = 0; read < fileBytes.length;) {
    numRead = diStream.read(fileBytes, read, fileBytes.length - read);
    if (numRead >= 0) {
        read = read + numRead;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not valid Java code. There is no `var` in Java. Perhaps you mean `int read`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this :

```
start_value = //....
for (read = start_value; read < fileBytes.length 
        && (numRead = diStream.read(fileBytes, read, fileBytes.length - read)) >= 0; 
        read += numRead) {

    //Your actions

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(numRead = diStream.read(fileBytes, read, fileBytes.length - read);
read < fileBytes.length && numRead >= 0;
numRead = diStream.read(fileBytes, read, fileBytes.length - read)) {
      read = read + numRead;
}
```